# Pros and Cons for Embedding Manifests

Tags: windows, dll, manifest

What are the pros and cons for [embedding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423492/how-do-i-add-a-manifest-to-an-executable-using-mt-exe) [manifests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w45z383.aspx)?

I know embedding manifests reduces the number of files you need to copy around, but what other effects are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error free: when renaming the exe file, you don't have to bother with renaming the corresponding manifest file.