# Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am using react native expo and trying to build project in android studio getting this error

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.

> Build command failed.
> Error while executing process C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.18.1\bin\ninja.exe with arguments {-C E:\My project\React-Native projects\CryptoWallet-DarkMode\expo-crypto-wallet\react-native-vrypto-wallet\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android.cxx\Debug\6d6s4v4m\arm64-v8a expo-modules-core}
> ninja: Entering directory `E:\My project\React-Native projects\CryptoWallet-DarkMode\expo-crypto-wallet\react-native-vrypto-wallet\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android.cxx\Debug\6d6s4v4m\arm64-v8a'
> [1/12] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/Exceptions.cpp.o
> [2/12] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptRuntime.cpp.o
> [3/12] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptValue.cpp.o
> [4/12] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptObject.cpp.o
> [5/12] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JNIFunctionBody.cpp.o
> [6/12] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/CachedReferencesRegistry.cpp.o
> [7/12] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JNIInjector.cpp.o
> [8/12] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/ExpoModulesHostObject.cpp.o
> [9/12] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JSIInteropModuleRegistry.cpp.o
> [10/12] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptModuleObject.cpp.o
> [11/12] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/MethodMetadata.cpp.o
> [12/12] Linking CXX shared library ........\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\6d6s4v4m\obj\arm64-v8a\libexpo-modules-core.so
> FAILED: ../../../../build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/6d6s4v4m/obj/arm64-v8a/libexpo-modules-core.so
> cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe --target=aarch64-none-linux-android21 --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc_real.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -shared -Wl,-soname,libexpo-modules-core.so -o ........\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\6d6s4v4m\obj\arm64-v8a\libexpo-modules-core.so CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/CachedReferencesRegistry.cpp.o CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/Exceptions.cpp.o CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/ExpoModulesHostObject.cpp.o CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JNIFunctionBody.cpp.o CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JNIInjector.cpp.o CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JSIInteropModuleRegistry.cpp.o CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptModuleObject.cpp.o CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptObject.cpp.o CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptRuntime.cpp.o CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptValue.cpp.o CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/MethodMetadata.cpp.o -L"E:/My project/React-Native projects/CryptoWallet-DarkMode/expo-crypto-wallet/react-native-vrypto-wallet/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/build/react-native-0.69.6-debug.aar/jni/arm64-v8a" -llog  -lfbjni  -ljsi  -lreactnativejni  -lfolly_runtime  -lreact_nativemodule_core  -landroid  -latomic -lm && cd ."
> C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot open output file ........\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\6d6s4v4m\obj\arm64-v8a\libexpo-modules-core.so: No such file or directory
> clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:buildCMakeDebug[armeabi-v7a]'.

> Build command failed.
> Error while executing process C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.18.1\bin\ninja.exe with arguments {-C E:\My project\React-Native projects\CryptoWallet-DarkMode\expo-crypto-wallet\react-native-vrypto-wallet\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android.cxx\Debug\6d6s4v4m\armeabi-v7a expo-modules-core}
> ninja: Entering directory `E:\My project\React-Native projects\CryptoWallet-DarkMode\expo-crypto-wallet\react-native-vrypto-wallet\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android.cxx\Debug\6d6s4v4m\armeabi-v7a'
> [1/12] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/Exceptions.cpp.o
> [2/12] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptValue.cpp.o
> [3/12] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptObject.cpp.o
> [4/12] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JNIFunctionBody.cpp.o
> [5/12] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/CachedReferencesRegistry.cpp.o
> [6/12] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JNIInjector.cpp.o
> [7/12] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/ExpoModulesHostObject.cpp.o
> [8/12] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JSIInteropModuleRegistry.cpp.o
> [9/12] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptRuntime.cpp.o
> [10/12] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptModuleObject.cpp.o
> [11/12] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/MethodMetadata.cpp.o
> [12/12] Linking CXX shared library ........\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\6d6s4v4m\obj\armeabi-v7a\libexpo-modules-core.so
> FAILED: ../../../../build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/6d6s4v4m/obj/armeabi-v7a/libexpo-modules-core.so
> cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi21 --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc_real.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--exclude-libs,libunwind.a -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -shared -Wl,-soname,libexpo-modules-core.so -o ........\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\6d6s4v4m\obj\armeabi-v7a\libexpo-modules-core.so CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/CachedReferencesRegistry.cpp.o CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/Exceptions.cpp.o CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/ExpoModulesHostObject.cpp.o CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JNIFunctionBody.cpp.o CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JNIInjector.cpp.o CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JSIInteropModuleRegistry.cpp.o CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptModuleObject.cpp.o CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptObject.cpp.o CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptRuntime.cpp.o CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptValue.cpp.o CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/MethodMetadata.cpp.o -L"E:/My project/React-Native projects/CryptoWallet-DarkMode/expo-crypto-wallet/react-native-vrypto-wallet/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/build/react-native-0.69.6-debug.aar/jni/armeabi-v7a" -llog  -lfbjni  -ljsi  -lreactnativejni  -lfolly_runtime  -lreact_nativemodule_core  -landroid  -latomic -lm && cd ."
> C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: fatal error: ........\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\6d6s4v4m\obj\armeabi-v7a\libexpo-modules-core.so: open: No such file or directory
> clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 14m 14s
482 actionable tasks: 403 executed, 79 up-to-date

[image]

Comment: I also have this issue building locally. However if I build with EAS it works. Although I would prefer to be able to build locally.

Comment: Same exact issue here, I am trying to find a solution but nothing seem working. Have you found a solution? Thank you

Comment: I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 5):

@swatantra-goswami I had the same issue as well! Deleting and re-installing node modules worked for me! Do try the same!

**Update**

For apple silicon chips, if you get the same error trying to build android, install Rosetta 2 and then try building it. Refer to the below link for the command to install.

The expo-av:configureCMakeDebug task uses the CMake version 3.18.1. For some reason, this version is not made for arm64 (m1 silicon), so I had to install de Rosetta 2.

Rosetta 2 enables a Mac with Apple silicon to use apps built for a Mac with an Intel processor.

To install Rosetta just run:

```
/usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

Close all terminal windows and re-run your command, in my case, yarn android

[Refer this GitHub issue link](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/20123)

Comment: Also have to delete `package-lock.json` as the issue is triggered by package versions

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue, however after reinitializing react-native app with `npx react-native@0.70.6 init` it worked properly with `expo-modules-core@1.1.1`.

I have used bare react-native (version 0.70.6) initialization. So, in order to add expo to an existing project see https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/

Have you checked these directories where `expo-modules-core.so` must be?
build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\6d6s4v4m\obj\armeabi-v7a
build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\6d6s4v4m\obj\armeabi-v8a

If `expo-modules-core.so` files exist in these folders and you use windows, then you probably have problem with win32 long paths. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry

In order to enable long paths, you need to enable them on system (see link above) and attach executable manifest to `ld` executable (see [How do I add a manifest to an executable using mt.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423492/how-do-i-add-a-manifest-to-an-executable-using-mt-exe)) which throws an error. In your case, you can see path to the `ld` executable in error log.

For manifest file I have used this configuration from https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/blob/master/windows/ninja.manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <application>
    <windowsSettings>
      <activeCodePage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2019/WindowsSettings">UTF-8</activeCodePage>
      <longPathAware  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">true</longPathAware>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure right build variant selected.
2. Check your supported JavaVersion in Android Studio: Project Setting> Build> BuildTools> Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

after some time searching for a solution, as deleting the node modules and cleaning the gradlew didn't work, I noticed that the issue could be related to the project path. Since the project was located in many subfolders, it ended up crashing at this point. I moved it to a folder directly on the C: drive and without any special characters in the folder names, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

i found it's really weird but what really worked for me was these steps:

- move project folder to shorter path (i move from very long path to just C://)
- completely delete android folder
- using `npm i` to reinstall
- using `npx expo-doctor`
- updating/upgrading whichever package said not compatible / warning by `npx expo-doctor`.

Let me know if this helps!